# How to render twig condition dynamically from php array

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

How to render twig condition dynamically from php array

**Php data array**

```
arry('label'=>'test','parentRoleExp'=>"is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') OR is_granted('ROLE_BLOG')"
```

**twig code**

```
{% set parentRoleExp = '' %}
 {% if link['parentRoleExp'] is defined %}
    {% set parentRoleExp = link['parentRoleExp'] %}
 {% endif %}
{% if parentRoleExp %}
  <h1>Admin Blog</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Blog <?h1>
{% endif %}
```

Above code not working

**Expected result**

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') OR is_granted('ROLE_BLOG') %}
  <h1>Admin Blog</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Blog <?h1>
{% endif %}
```

I tried with various method but not working. please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't make it interpret a string as code. Is there a reason you don't get the actual value in the controller and just send a boolean?

Answer (score 1):

it's very bad idea - ulnerability

But if you want... register eval() function:

```
$twig = new Twig\Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction(new Twig\TwigFunction('phpEval', 'eval'));
```

in template

```
{% if phpEval(parentRoleExp) %}
```